# How to access key and value of an array in smarty template?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

I'm assigning an array named `$enquiries_labels` **from php file to a smarty template file**. If I print the array in PHP file it's output is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => New Enquiry
    [1] => Retail Enquiry
    [2] => Feedback
    [3] => Payment Query
    [4] => Package Query
    [5] => Test Query
)
```

Now after assigning this array to a smarty file I want to access these values in a select HTML control. For it I need to use foreach loop construct of smarty template engine. If a pre-selected value is matching with the key from array then I'll keep that value selected. For achieving this I tried below code, but it didn't work for me. Can anyone help me in this regard please? For your reference I'm putting below the code I tried in smarty template:

```
<select name="contact_label" id="contact_label"> 
{if $enquiries_labels}
                  {foreach from=$enquiries_labels item=label}
                    <option value="{$label.key}" {if $data.key == $label.key} selected="selected" {/if}>{$label.value}
                    </option>
                  {/foreach}
                {/if}
      </select>
```

Thanks for spending some of your valuable time in understanding my issue.

Comment: In this special case (building options for a <select>) you could just use `{html_options options=$enquiries_labels selected=$data.key name="contact_label" id="contact_label"}`. Smarty will generate the complete <select> and <option> tags for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `key` in your `foreach`:

```
{foreach from=$enquiries_labels item=label key=key}
          <option value="{$key}" {if $data.key == $key} selected="selected" {/if}>{$label}
          </option>
{/foreach}
```

It's all there in the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl).

Answer (score 7):

Smarty 3 foreach construction is like this

```
{foreach $products as $p}
    {$p@key}: {$p}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: This is so much simpler and elegant

Comment: Why not `{foreach $products as $key => $p} ...`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `key` attribute.

```
{foreach from=$enquiries_labels item="label" key="key"}
    <option value="{$key}"{if $data.key == $key} selected="selected"{/if}>{$label}</option>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

this also works

```
{foreach $products as $product}
    key: {$product@key} -> value: {$product@value} 
{/foreach}

{$product@value} = {$product}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```php
{foreach $enquiries_labels as $key => $value}
  <option value="{$key}" {if $data.key == $key} selected="selected" {/if}>
    {$value}
  </option>
{/foreach}
```